# Load models from remote URL with ThreeJS/FIber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I've started learning Threejs and I was wondering if it is possible to load 3d models using a remote URL, when I was reading [drei's documentation](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#usegltf), I noticed a `URL` parameter though the [storybook](https://drei.pmnd.rs/?path=/story/loaders-gltf--use-gltf-scene-st) seems to load the 3d model from a local resource and I haven't found  an example which uses a remote resource.

> It defaults to CDN loaded draco binaries (https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/) which are only loaded for compressed models.

Ideally I would like to include a URL to a 3d model in a JSON field for an object I would like to rendering my react application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I uploaded my model into an AWS bucket and enabled CORS, I was scared alot of config would have been needed, but this seems to work fine:

```
function Model(props: any) {
  const { scene } = useGLTF(
    "https://s3.amazonaws.com/model.foo/bar.glb"
  );
  return <primitive object={scene} {...props} />;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I have the same problem and stack. Thanks for sharing